# Renaming batch files, but error occurs when there is space in the file name. Need a fix! Bash

Tags: macos, bash, unix, batch-file, rename

So my code works. It's doing what I want to. Essentially my script renames files to match the last two directories in which  they are placed, followed by zero padding. Also it takes an argument where if you type in the directory it'll change the files in the specified directory.

Here's my code:

```
r="$@"
if [ -d "$r" ]; then            # if string exists and is a directory then do the following commands
  cd "$r"                       # change directory to the specified name
  echo "$r"                     # print directory name
elif [ -z "$1" ]; then          # if string argument is null then do following command
  echo "Current Directory"      # Print Current Directory
else                            # if string is not a directory or null then do nothing
  echo "No such Directory"      # print No such Directory
fi

e=`pwd | awk -F/ '{ print $(NF-1) "_" $NF }'`   # print current directory | print only the last two fields
echo $e
X=1;
for i in `ls -1`; do                            # loop. rename all files in directory to "$e" with 4 zeroes padding.
  mv $i $e.$(printf %04d.%s ${X%.*} ${i##*.})   # only .jpg files for now, but can be changed to all files.
  let X="$X+1"
done
```

And here is the output:

```
Testdir_pics.0001.jpg
Testdir_pics.0002.jpg
...
```

However, just as the title suggests, it creates errors when the filenames have spaces in them. How do I fix this?

Comment: You have tagged your question with OSX, Bash, Unix, and Batch (Windows).  Which system are you actually on??

Comment: Run your script through [SpellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: Sorry, I'm just using terminal in my Mac OSX

Answer (score 2):

If there are spaces in the file names, then these two lines will fail:

```
for i in `ls -1`; do 
  mv $i $e.$(printf %04d.%s ${X%.*} ${i##*.})
```

Replace them with:

```
for i in *; do 
  mv "$i" "$e.$(printf %04d.%s "${X%.*}" "${i##*.}")"
```

Comments:

- `for i in *` will work for all file names even those with the most difficult characters.  By contrast, the `for i in $(ls -1)` formulation is very fragile.
- Unless, for some strange reason, you really want word splitting to be performed on your variables, always place them in double-quotes.  Thus, `mv $i ...` should be replaced with `mv "$1" ...`.

Comment: Always quote variable expansions unless you know you have a reason not to. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for the `ls -1` -> `*` change.